# HTTP error 508 from PERL script during redirection of requests from secure to non-secure server

Tags: perl, http, tomcat

I am getting a strange error in my file upload application.

1) Server 1: It is secure web server on port 443, which is accessible to public hosting a perl script

2)  When this server get a request for cgi-bin directory, it will simple redirect the request to other web server (Server 2) running on port 80

3) The perl script in Server 2 will save the file in disk

Issue:

Above mechanism worked for a couple of hours later it has thrown Http error code:508

Observations:

If I directly hit Server2 on port 80, perl script successfully saving the files to disk. But If I directly hit Server1 on port 443, I am getting 508 error

When I first got the issue, I have restarted both webservers and it worked. But when I get the same issue second time, restart of servers did not help. The call to Server1 is throwing 508 error and requests are getting timed out.

ulimits and open files are in control.

If you experience this type of issue, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Show your code (html form with upload field, and both perl scripts). Btw. why have you tagged your question with `java` and `tomcat`? Do you run your CGI scripts in Tomcat (as described in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cgi-howto.html)?

Comment: I do not have any UI for it. On certain condition, the standalone application over the internet will upload the file on machine by invoking a perl script. tomcat do not have role to play but the server hosts both apache & tomact . Perl is served by apache. Nothing much in perl script except creating a directory with a user name & and saving on disk with  fileWrite($data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strange issue has been resolved after moving dynamic service to other Virtual machine. This issue is no longer reproducible after changing the node.